# Geb Select a tag based on text

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

I am trying to select based on text, I use the following to select

```
$("div[class='ui-datatable-tablewrapper']").find("span:contains('Person Name')")
```

i get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I believe it's because of the "contains" selector in jquery. How do I achieve the same in geb.

Html:

```
<div class="ui-datatable-tablewrapper">
                        <table role="grid">
                            <thead id="searchForm:singleStaffDT_head">
                                <tr role="row">
                                    <th id="searchForm:singleStaffDT:j_id_7s" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"
                                        aria-label="Person ID" scope="col" style="width:15%">
                                        <span class="ui-column-title">Person ID</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th id="searchForm:singleStaffDT:j_id_7u" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"
                                        aria-label="Person Name" scope="col" style="width:25%">
                                        <span class="ui-column-title">Person Name</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th id="searchForm:singleStaffDT:j_id_7w" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"
                                        aria-label="Organization" scope="col" style="width:25%">
                                        <span class="ui-column-title">Organization</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th id="searchForm:singleStaffDT:j_id_7y" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"
                                        aria-label="Staff Role" scope="col" style="width:25%">
                                        <span class="ui-column-title">Staff Role</span>
                                    </th>
                                    <th id="searchForm:singleStaffDT:j_id_80" class="ui-state-default" role="columnheader"
                                        aria-label="" scope="col" style="width:10%">
                                        <span class="ui-column-title">Action
                                            <BR />[Select]</span>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="searchForm:singleStaffDT_data" class="ui-datatable-data ui-widget-content">
                                <tr class="ui-widget-content ui-datatable-empty-message">
                                    <td colspan="5"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Comment: could you post HTML code also

Comment: added the HTML code

Comment: What do you want to select? Want to get the value of Person Name field?

Comment: @eduPeeth yes i want to select that

Comment: Please try what I suggested below, in your technology and lemme know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a "contains" search, you want to write your code in a similar pattern to this:

```
$("span", text: contains("Person Name"))
```

You could also do something like this in your page object (i think!):

```
    personName { $('span').find(text: 'Person Name') }
```

Or:

```
    personName { find('span', text: 'Person Name') }
```